# Refresh provider at Dagger Hilt in the same fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have two instances of the [Apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin) client.
The first has a static baseURL, and
the second one has a baseURL returned from the first request.

[Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/): it's providing the two providers at the same time when the app launched,

How can I solve it?

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("first")
fun provideApolloSecondaryClient(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
): ApolloClient {
    return ApolloClient.Builder()
        .serverUrl(STAGING_URL)
        .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("second")
fun provideApolloClient(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
     userPreferences: UserPreferences
): ApolloClient {

    val connectionURL =
        runBlocking { userPreferences.networkKeys.first() }

    return ApolloClient.Builder()
        .serverUrl(connectionURL)
        .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}
```

I need to provide the second provider only and update the first provider or refresh it.